# How do I implemented Oculus headset video screencapping in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, screen-recording, oculusquest

I want to implement the functionality of video recording in Oculus headset in Unity C#. I'd like it to run correctly both on Oculus headset (Android build) and PC build if possible.

I've tried multiple different solutions, such as saving a recording to Android using a Unity package I found, which didn't work in PC.

I also tried recording via adb screen record which didn't work out well as it shows the two lenses instead of a smooth VR recording (see image here).
[image]

Can anyone recommend solutions I could try, or possible Unity packages they could recommend me?

Thank you very much. Apologies if this is a repeat question, I searched thru StackOverflow but couldn't find any solutions that suited my needs.

Comment: Not sure this is on topic for programming site, but if you search for RockVR on the asset store there's a VR recorder asset that seems useful. Not updated recently, no idea if it'll still work for you.

Comment: @Corey Thank you for the recommendation! Unfortunately it seems that RockVR doesn't support the Oculus Quest, which is what I'm currently working with.